# Loop keeps returning to wrong part

Tags: python, menu, bmi

I'm taking a fundamentals of programming class and we're supposed to be building a menu that calculates BMI and also shows different gym membership options, what I can't figure out is why my menu keeps looping back to the BMI calculator after viewing the membership rates.

this is some of my code:

```py
def mainmenu():
    option = int(input("Enter your option:  "))

    while option != 0:
        if option == 1:
            try: 
                print("Calculate BMI")
                the_height = float(input("Enter the height in cm: "))
                assert the_height > 0
                the_weight = float(input("Enter the weight in kg: "))
                assert the_weight > 0         
                the_BMI = the_weight / (the_height/100)**2  
            except ValueError: 
                print("Enter height and weight in whole numbers")
        
            print("Your BMI is", the_BMI)
            if the_BMI <= 18.5:  
                print("You are underweight.")  
            elif the_BMI <= 24.9:  
                print("You are Normal.")  
            elif the_BMI <= 29.9:  
                print("You are overweight.")  
            else:
                print("You are obese.")
            check = input("Do you want to quit or start again, enter Y to restart or another to end ?: ")
            if check.upper() == "Y":  
                print("Bye...")
            mainmenu() 

    elif option == 2:
        def submenu():
            print("Choose your membership type")
            print("[1] Bassic")
            print("[2] Regular")
            print("[3] Premium")
            print("[0] Exit to main menu")

        loop = True
        while loop:
                submenu()
                option = int(input("Enter your option:  "))
                if option == 1:
                    print("Basic Membership")
                    print("$10 per week, $40 per month")
                    break
               
                

                elif option == 2:
                    print("Regular Membership")
                    print("$15 per week, $60 per month")
                    check = input("Do you want to quit or start again, enter Y to restart or another to end ?: ")
                    if check.upper() == "Y":
                        submenu()   
                    
                
                elif option == 3:
                    print("Premium Membership")
                    print("$20 per week, $80 per month")
                    check = input("Do you want to quit or start again, enter Y to restart or another to end ?: ")
                    if check.upper() == "Y":
                        submenu()    

                elif option == 0:
                    loop = False
                
        else:
            break    

    else:
        print("Invalid option....")
        break
        
mainmenu()
option = int(input("Enter your option:  "))
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, I've been playing around for a while and can't find the solution.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the reason for this is that you're using `option` variable to store the value that user provide for both main menu and sub menu.

Instead of this

```
submenu()
option = int(input("Enter your option:  "))
```

Use

```
submenu()
submenu_option = int(input("Enter your option:  "))
```

Also replace the `option` with `submenu_option` only where you wants to refer to the user selection for the sub menu